# Why the context of the file cannot read from the txt file?

Tags: python

I have creat a new empty txt file, but the code below read and write it.

```
f = open('users.txt', 'r+')
users = eval(f.read())  #f.read()read a string，eval()transfer string to dict
for i in range(4):
    name = input('Input Username： ')
    passwd = input('Input password： ')
    c_passwd = input('Confirm password again： ')
    if len(name.strip()) != 0 and name not in users and len(passwd.strip()) != 0 and passwd == c_passwd:
        users[name]= {'passwd':passwd, 'role':1} #insert new data, role 1: Customer; role 2: Restaurant; role 3: Admin
        f.seek(0)
        f.truncate()  #clear file
        f.writelines(str(users)) #write data to file from dict
        print('Congratulations, Register Success. ')
        f.close()
        break
    elif len(name.strip()) == 0:
        print('Username could not be empty. Remain %d chance' %(3-i))
    elif name in users:
        print('Username repeat. Remain %d chance' %(3-i))
    elif len(passwd.strip()) == 0:
        print('Password could not be empty. Remain %d chance' %(3-i))
    elif c_passwd != passwd:
        print('Password not same. Remain %d chance' %(3-i))

#log in
f = open('users.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8')
users = eval(f.read())
for count in range(3):
    name = input('Input Username： ')
    password = input('Input password： ')
    if name in users and password == users[name]['passwd']:
        print('Log in successful！')
        break
    else:
        print('Username or/and Password is/are wrong,You still have %d chance'%(2-count))
f.close()
```

The System showed

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/zskjames/PycharmProjects/Fit5136/Register, log in.py", line 4, in <module>
    users = eval(f.read()) #f.read()read a string，eval()transfer string to dict
  File "<string>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Do anybody could tell me how to fix that? And how to avoid this mistakes in the future.

Comment: `eval` does not "transfer" to string, it executes the string it gets: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval

Comment: By the way, these code is order to achieve register and login function

Comment: Use a pickle instead:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html

Answer (score 1):

You probably want your text file to contain JSON, in order to easily interact with it and turn it into a `dict`.

In order to do that, you would need to replace your `eval` with a [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html):

```py
import json

with open('users.txt', 'r+') as f:
    users = json.load(f)
    # rest of your code
```

In order for it to work, your text file should look something like the following:

```
{"John Doe": {"passwd": "somepass", "role": 1}}
```

In addition, you need to replace:

```py
f.writelines(str(users)) #write data to file from dict
```

to:

```py
json.dump(users, f)
```